# Are possible square roots modulo $p$ and $q$ evenly distributed?

Tags: number-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, radicals

Can someone please prove that $\sqrt{a} \bmod p$, for some prime $p$, and $\sqrt{a} \bmod q$, for some prime $q$, evenly distributed?

In other words, modulo all primes, either $\sqrt{a}$ is an integer modulo some prime, or it basically does not exist as an integer.  I want to know if I can expect this distribution to be random.  For instance, if I pick a set of primes, can I expect $\sqrt{a}$ to have approximately a 50% chance of existing modulo each prime?

One other thing...  It would be helpful to know if $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are independent modulo the same prime, for randomly chosen $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The only solutions to $x^2\equiv n^2\pmod r$ with $r$ prime are $x\equiv\pm n\pmod r$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I'm not sure I follow... I'm just trying to determine that if we pick a number, call it $a$, then if we pick two primes at random, call them $p$ and $q$ with $\sqrt{a} < p \le q$, then $\sqrt{a}$ has a 50% chance of "existing" modulo $p$, and a 50% chance of "existing" modulo $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. $a \equiv b^2 \mod p$ has either two solutions or none. So the preimage of $a$ under the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is either empty or consists of two elements, showing that the squaring function $\Bbb Z_p \to \Bbb Z_p$ has an image of cardinality $(p-1)/2$.

Therefore you're right: for arbitrary $a$, save for cases where $p \mid a$, there is a $50\%$ chance that $a$ is a square modulo $p$.