# Are cube roots evenly distributed modulo primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, cubic-reciprocity

Are the cube roots of two integers chosen from a uniform distribution between $1$ and $p-1$ inclusive, $p$ prime, essentially evenly distributed?  Note that I will use a $p$ such that $p$ is not equivalent to $2$ modulo $3$.

In other words, I'm trying to ensure that if I pick a random number between $1$ and $p-1$ I will have an equal chance of that number being the cube of some integer.

I've searched the site for answers, but my search did not come up with anything, and I don't know enough theory, except for maybe trying to read more on cubic reciprocity.

---

I've found a similar result for square roots [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420569/are-possible-square-roots-modulo-p-and-q-evenly-distributed).

Comment: If $p\equiv1\pmod3$ then there are $\frac13(p-1)$ cubic residues modulo $p$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: $a^3\equiv b $ doesn't  have solutions for all  $b\pmod p$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I think I realized why my question doesn't make sense... I pick two numbers, $\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{y}$.  Then I go through a bunch of primes trying to determine which of these cube roots will "exist" modulo the primes.  I'm hoping that I can treat them as "evenly distributed", or having equal probability of "existing".

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  See my reply to LordSharktheUnknown...  I'm really just trying to find when the roots exist modulo various $p$, $p$ prime.

Comment: You are asking if $2,3$ have (almost) the same probability of being cubes $\bmod p$ when $p\le N$ is chosen uniformly and $N\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Taking up 1/3 of the set does not amount to "evenly distributed", that is not proved even for square roots under your link. They could all be clustered.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, except the numbers could be any values, and not limited to $2$ or $3$...  I don't know for sure if the $2$ or $3$ makes a difference.

Comment: It is obvious the answer for $2,3$ extends to $x,y$ (say distinct sqaurefree). Please edit your question.

Comment: Assuming that $p$ is a large prime $\equiv1\pmod3$ then the so called Polya-Vinogradov method for studying incomplete character sums leads to the result that an interval $[a,b]$, $0<a<b<p$, contains roughly $(b-a)/3$ cubic residues. The error terms have the order $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt p\cdot \ln p)$, so you still want $(b-a)$ to be large in comparison to $\sqrt{p}\cdot\ln p$ for this result to kick in. Anyway, it shows that the cubic residues are relatively evenly distributed. IOW not *clustered* in the sense @Conifold may have intended.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Your answer looks like the one I've been looking for.  I believe I'll accept a proof of this.

Comment: @MattGroff Before I try and compose an answer I need to check one thing. This and your other question suggest to me that you may have in mind a question where you fix $a$ and let $p$ vary. In the answer I have in mind we first fix a large prime $p$, and then study the distribution of cubic residues modulo $p$. Can you clarify this, please?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I fix $a$ and let $p$ vary.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No harm done :-) I simply brought up a related fact I can prove. In case it might be useful to you. Your actual question is more difficult. At least to me. In a sense a random integer is a cubic residue modulo a prime $p$ with probability $1/3$, but we need to define the problem a bit more carefully. For example, $8$ is obviously a cubic residue modulo all primes :-)

Comment: Mind you, cubic reciprocity may allow something interesting to be said about this theme, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I see what you're saying.  I don't see how any specific choice of $a$ will make a difference at this point, so you can choose $a$ to make life easier.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes cubic reciprocity works, it suffices to show $(\frac{a}{\pi})_3$ (for $(\pi)$ prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$) is a non-trivial Hecke character, so is $(-1)^{(N(\pi)-1/3}$, with the PNT for Hecke characters we get the same asymptotic as given by Chebotarev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of your question is when we fix two (distinct cube free) positive integers $a,b$ and we choose randomly uniformly a prime $p\le N$ are the probabilities that $a$ and $b$ are cubes $\bmod p$ roughly equal (as $N$ gets large).

The answer is yes, because [Chebotarev theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem) tells us the asymptotic $$\#\{ p \le N, x^3-a\bmod p \text{ has a root }\}\sim \frac{|H|}{|G|} \frac{N}{\log N}$$ where $G=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(a^{1/3},\zeta_3)/\Bbb{Q}), |G|=6$ and $H$ is the set of $\sigma \in G$ such that $\sigma(a^{1/3})=a^{1/3}$, ie. $|H| = 2$ independently of $a$.